# Using Emma without Junit through Jenkins + ANT + Android

Tags: java, android, ant, junit, jenkins

I need to prepare a reporting system which will be displayed the code parts are used and not used by the application and in this particular case I'm going to use EMMA. However there will be no any test code next to project and emma will scan only the methods and give such a report like "20% are not using, %80 are in use" etc...

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes how should I configure ant without junit? (Please share sample ant code)
3. Do I need to make something additional to work with jenkins?

Comment: At my former company we were using EMMA and Hudson but the thing is we had test apps. Each library had its own test app. I would advise you to try search for plugins for eclipse, I remember there was one checking for how often some methods are or you can try to use Android Traceview. That one will tell the exact number of calls per class and app. Now, regarding Jenkins, I know I searched for something similar and at that time it wasn't possible. I cannot say 100% because it wasn't in my search criteria.

Comment: I see but I need to make all of these actions via jenkins. There are lots of programmers here and they intend to see coverage results after every apk has been output. Do you have any ANT configuration which is able to run EMMA? No matter if there is junit or not. I'm in this point right now.

Comment: Ok. So, If I post a configuration where you have a normal library and a test library for this app, would that be sufficient for you?.(for the test library you will be able to see test coverage via emma).

Comment: at least it can show me a way of doing

Comment: Another question. Do you need to know how can you configure Hudson - via Tomcat and so on. Or is it enough for you if I just provide to you the xml for test application?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to provide an answer after all even though you didn't tell what exactly you have and need. 
**Step 1**. The first thing to do is to configure Hudson. First step I did was to download hudson war file and run it.
**Step 2**. What I did here was to start it via java command line and configure the plugins that I need. In your case the plugins are svn, git and android emulator. See below how to configure Hudson. 
[Configure Hudson Link 1](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_hudson.htm) 
[Configure Hudson Link 2](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch03.html) 
Next, I downloaded tomcat and I configured the web.xml file from webapps/hudson/web-inf to link to the hudson home just created earlier. 
Now, once you managed to run hudson properly, you can start configuring hudson and next the jobs. 
**Step 3**. Configuring Hudson. You start by configuring Hudson, by setting up the plugins you need, like Apache Ant, Android Emulator, etc.
**Step 4**. Configuring jobs. You have two type of jobs: normal and test.
See below a printscreen for the required configuration.
[image: Hudson General Configuration] 
Common things for both jobs is the repository URL of your online URL, SVN, Git, etc. 
A printscreen for a normal job can be seen at: [image: Hudson normal Job]
For the test job on the other hand you have to configure a bit more. You start by configuring the build environment. If you installed the Android Emulator plugin you should see options " Run an Android emulator during build". This has to be checked together with some other information. A small tutorial can be found here. I would say it is pretty similar.
[Android on Hudson](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html).
Once you achieved this, further on you configure ant. Here, you check the Ant version to be one that you set before in the general settings section and, as for the targets, I used the following option: 
"clean-set-absolute-tested-path emma instrument nodeps verbose-output-file-for-emma install test fetch-test-report". 
Now, in order to see the coverage reports, I used a plugin that allows you to publish the coverage reports as an HTML page and this option can be found at the post-build actions step. For a better understanding see the image:
[image: Hudson Test project job part 1] 
[image: Hudson Test project job part 2]
 
**Step 5**. Configuring the xml files.
Now, once hudson is done, further on you start configuring the project in eclipse. You start by creating a test project for your app(I hope you know how to do that) and after that you create the files ant.properties, build.xml and project.properties.
At first, you create the build xml and the ant properties files for the library.
An example of a build xml for the library can be found at: 
http://pastebin.com/WiD2Y6j4 
Also, the ant.properties for the library can be found at:
http://pastebin.com/cpuGVDhL 
Further on, you need the configuration for the test app. Build xml:
http://pastebin.com/yjC8TViT 
Ant properties: 
http://pastebin.com/5STqMV6b 
Once you have committed your code  and run the jobs you created before, you should be able to see the html report for your code, classes %, methods % and even what your logic tested. However, from my experience the latter(logic testing) has not proven to be quite an exact science.
Hope it helps. That's pretty much the configuration we use at my work. So far was successful.

Comment: It is ok, never said that.It is just I also have no time and I was expecting a quick answer because as you can see it is a lot to explain and I am sure I forgot something. If so, please ask.